# In Open Atrium is there a way to assign a user to a case that user is not in?

Tags: distributions

I would like to be able to have an admin be assigned to a case that is in a group that user is not a part of. In Open Atrium. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible, at least not by using the Atrium web UI out-of-the-box. Cases can only be assigned to users in the current group.